# How to change datatype with key in oracle?

Tags: oracle, vb6

My front end code is:

```
PRIVATE SUB FORM_LOAD()
.Open SQL, CON, 1, 2
If .RecordCount > 0 Then
Combo4.Clear
.MoveFirst
Do While Not .EOF
Combo4.AddItem .Fields("ASSET_NAME").Value
Combo4.ItemData(Combo4.NewIndex) = .Fields("AID").Value
.MoveNext
Loop
Else
Combo4.Clear
End If
.Close
END SUB
```

My Oracle table looks like this:

```
SQL> DESC ASSET
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 -------------------------------- -------- -------------
 AID                                       NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 ASSET_NAME                                         VARCHAR2(50)
 LOC_ID                                             NUMBER(38)
 UNIT                                               VARCHAR2(25)
 SUP_ID                                             NUMBER(38)
 BITT                                               VARCHAR2(5)

SQL>
```

AID is the primary key of the ASSET table with a datatype of INT.  But at the front end I gets a runtime error of  `'6' OVERFLOW`.  So  I decided  to change the datatype of AID column.  Unfortunately I get this error:

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE ASSET
  2  MODIFY AID DOUBLE;
MODIFY AID DOUBLE
            *
 ERROR at line 2:
     ORA-00905: missing keyword
SQL>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DOUBLE` is not an Oracle datatype,  You can use `BINARY_DOUBLE` or `FLOAT()`.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#i45441).

Having said which, neither is the right choice for something which is supposed to hold  integers.  Also they're a bad choice for primary keys.  Stick with `NUMBER`.

If you're getting a VB overflow error you can reduce the precision.  Something like `NUMBER(12,0)` (or whatever value makes a safe ceiling for your business rules).

Note that we cannot change the datatype of a populated column, only empty ones.